# Best way to iterate through dict of pandas dataframes with identical structures, to generate one dataframe with the sum of each (row, col) element?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a pandas dict, d1, where each value is a two-column (ID and Weight), 100-row dataframe.

I want to iterate through the dict, and for each dataframe, I want to sum all the 'Weight' values in row n, where n is the value between 1 and 100 representing the row. I then want to write the output to another dict, d2, where the key is 1-100, and the value is the sum of the values.

Example d1 value dataframe:

```
ID    Weight
1     0.021
2     0.445
3     1.018
..
..
..
99    77.31
100   234.04
```

Essentially, imagine I have 10000 of these dataframes, and I want to sum all the Weight values for ID 1 across the 10000, then all the Weight values for ID 2 across the 10000, and so on up to ID 100.

I have a solution, which is basically a nested loop. It works, and it will do. However, I'm really keen to expand my basic pandas / numpy knowledge, and I wondered if there is a more pythonic way to do this?

My existing code :

```
for i in range (1,101):
    tot = 0
    for key, value in d1.items():
        tot = tot + value.at[i,'Weight']
    d2[i] = tot
```

Hugely appreciate any help and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas add function:

```
#create a zero filled dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(len(df1)), columns=df1.columns)
#iterate through dict and add values to df
for value in d1.values():
  df = df.add(value)
```

You can set your `ID` as index via `df_i = df_i.set_index('ID')` and then add them all up, so that only weights are added and then `df=df.reset_index()` at the end.
Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)], columns=['ID','Weight'])
   ID  Weight
0   1       2
1   3       4
2   5       6

df2 = pd.DataFrame([(10,20),(30,40),(50,60)], columns=['ID','Weight'])
   ID  Weight
0  10      20
1  30      40
2  50      60

df3 = pd.DataFrame([(100,200),(300,400),(500,600)], columns=['ID','Weight'])
    ID  Weight
0  100     200
1  300     400
2  500     600

d1 = {'df1':df1,'df2':df2,'df3':df3}
df = pd.DataFrame(0, index=np.arange(len(df1)), columns=df1.columns)
print(df)
for value in d1.values():
  df = df.add(value)
```

df:

```
    ID  Weight
0  111     222
1  333     444
2  555     666
```

Comment: Ehsan, thank you very much for your detailed response - I had completely missed the pandas add function - this is going to be hugely useful to me going forward. I really appreciate it.

Once I can upvote I will be back to do so with your answer!


edit: Seems I can now upvote!